# Installing python-praat-scripts in Ubuntu

Tags: python, praat

I want to install the [python-praat-scripts](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-praat-scripts/0.2.2) package. It says:

> ## Installation
>
> You can install python-praat-scripts through pip via:
>
> `pip install python-praat-scripts`
>
> Or through downloading this repository and running:
>
> `python setup.py install`
>
> Once installed, the `praatinterface` package will be importable.

So I did that. Then it says:

> For basic usage, instantiate a PraatLoader object as below:
>
> ``` from praatinterface import PraatLoader
>
> pl = PraatLoader(praatpath = '/path/to/praat')
>
> text = pl.run_script('formants.praat', '/path/to/wav/file', 5, 5500)
>
> formants = pl.read_praat_out(text) ```

So I wrote the following:

```
from praatinterface import PraatLoader

praat_path = '/usr/bin/praat'
pl = PraatLoader(praatpath = praat_path)
for path in ae_paths:
    text = pl.run_script('formants.praat', path, 5, 5500)
    formants = pl.read_praat_out(text)
    print(formants)
```

here `ae_paths` is a list with audio paths. The praat path was found by writing in the terminal:

> vladimir@vladimir:/usr/bin$ type praat
>
> praat is /usr/bin/praat

However I get an error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 
>         3 praat_path = '/usr/bin/praat'
>   ----> 4 pl = PraatLoader(praatpath = praat_path)
>         5 for path in ae_paths:
>         6     text = pl.run_script('formants.praat', path, 5, 5500)
>
> /home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/praatinterface/Praat.py
>   in **init**(self, **kwargs)
>        18             self.script_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**),'praatScripts')
>        19             self.praat = 'praat'
>   ---> 20         self.init_scripts()
>        21         if self.debug:
>        22             self.initlog()
>
> /home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/praatinterface/Praat.py
>   in init_scripts(self)
>        35     def init_scripts(self):
>        36         if not os.path.isdir(self.script_dir):
>   ---> 37             os.mkdir(self.script_dir)
>        38         for s in self.scripts:
>        39             sfilename = s
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/praatScripts'

Comment: For some reason, the Python wrapper around praat is trying to create a praatScripts directory if it's not there, right next to the /usr/bin/praat executable. Of course, that requires root permission. But overall, it simply should not do this; it's just bad practice. I'm inclined to say: avoid this package.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try and create virtualenv and work in that, since that environment will be owned by you. But it's a work-around, not a real solution to the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can take up this issue with the author, and ask what their actual intention is. But it feels very un-system like to have a directory /usr/bin/praatScripts/ .

Comment: @Evert Trying [this](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/christian.herbst//python/#topOfPage) but still getting other kind of errors.

Comment: "other kind of errors" is obviously a different (new) question.

Comment: You also point to a completely other example, without mentioning if you already solved your actual problem stated here. (Besides, "this" is a rather generic pointer to a page with a dozen code samples. You'll want to ask a new question then, detailing what you attempt to do and what the error is, as you've done here.)

Answer (score 0):

I have another way to run praat scripts.
you can try this way.

First you have to install praat to run python praat scripts
- you can install praat using this   "sudo apt-get install praat"

- after that open praat GUI using "./praat" command in CMD.
- there is option run to praat scripts. click on it and select your praat script and execute.